# Retrieve Connected Components Graphstream

Tags: java, graphstream

I am using GraphStream in a project and my problem is that I want to retrieve the list of connected components but I only get either their count or at the very best their Ids.

I have tried this code but it doesn't return anything :

```
ConnectedComponents cc = new ConnectedComponents();
cc.init(graph);
System.out.println("List of Connected Components :");
for(ConnectedComponent conn : cc) {
   System.out.println("Component " + conn.id + " :");
   System.out.println("--------------");
   for(Node n : conn.getEachNode()) {
      Object[] attr = n.getAttribute("xy");
      Double x = (Double) attr[0];
      Double y = (Double) attr[1];
      System.out.println(x + " , " + y);
    }
}
```

The nodes have an attribute "xy" which contains the coordinates stored as Double[].

What did I do wrong? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConnectedComponents` has been rewritten in commit on [2015-12-15](https://github.com/graphstream/gs-algo/commit/7a068b2591d952c54d78f5d4d22a25477d9341cd). There was a problem with retrieving content of components.

If you are not using the git version of GraphStream, maybe you should give it a try.